# Jquery offset with % instead of px - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script were i want it to make an offset for 15% top of the id its scrolling to. I have try many things, so im kinda curious what approach you guys would take. I have stripped it down to what works, since all of my own attempts failed. Hope someone can help me out.

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 800, function () {
            location.hash = target; 
        });

        return false;
    });
```

i made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/77rFz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try it, but I would say something like this could work:

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr("href");

    var offset = $(target).offset().top - $(target).height * 0.15;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 800, function () {
        location.hash = target; 
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: If i remove the location.hash = target it stops the flickering, but then it starts to miscalculate when i hit link 2, 3 etc.

Comment: True, I've a updated the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/77rFz/44/) and will update the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Math.round(parseInt($(target).offset().top) * 0.15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        var parentDiv = $(this).parent(".wrap1");
        var offset = Math.round(parseInt($(target).offset().top) - (0.15 * parentDiv.height()));

        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 800, function () {
            //location.hash = target; 
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to the same just some minutes ago. Btw the `location.hash = target` should not make any problems

Comment: You're not setting the radix of the `parstInt` function. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt